# Customize syntax highlighting in visual studio for C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I've been unable to find within visual studio 2013, how to change the syntax highlighting color scheme for C# files.

Namely, I'd want to change the color of variable names, and method names in method declaration lines.

Any ideas on where I can tweak these colors? I can select light/dark/blue color schemes but not specific syntax colors. In Options / Fonts and Colors there is nothing for C# (only a few options for C++).

Edit:

Ok, so I found where you can set the colors, it was in Options / Fonts and Colors after all. There is general settings (keyword, user types, etc), and C++ specific settings, but no C# specific settings. So you just need to set the general settings.

I still wasn't able to find how to color the method name in method declarations in a different color. When I want to change a method, having the method name declarations in different colors really help me (when using MonoDevelop), and I would really like to set it in visual studio.

```
public void MyMethod(int someVariable) { 
    MyMethod(someVariable+1);
}
```

I'd like to have different color for "MyMethod" word in the declaration line than the second line (where I recursively call it).

Comment: You have the full version of Visual Studio 2013 correct.  If you have an `Express` versions specify what you have.  I promise you options for C# language syntax is there.

Comment: I have full version of Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Answer (score -1):

try the extension Codinion (http://www.codinion.com or https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/504311cf-bd01-4b12-bca3-a3e5d9505b76) which gives you full syntax highlighting for c#.